# Mapping json data with serializer fails validation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Not able to map the json data field in serializer field. I tried with `source` but it seems it only works for model field. Is there any way to map this field...?? In my usecase I will be having around 10-15 fields in total to be mapped in this serializer...

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class Test(serializers.Serializer):
    my_field = serializers.CharField(source='myOtherField', required=True)

test_data = {'myOtherField': 'test2'}
test = Test(data=test_data)
test.is_valid()
print(test.data)
```

Validation is failing. If I remove the validation and just pass test_data without `data=` like this `test = Test(test_data)` then it works fine.

Comment: What does `serializers.error` return?

Comment: `{'my_field': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}`